# How to set folder write permissions for application add-on with python

Tags: python, permissions, path

I have python script that works fine but only when run as stand-alone, while I need it as a script. It uses external .exe compiled C library in such manner:

```
# trigger the shell command

import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('qvoronoi TI data.txt TO results.txt p FN Fv QJ', shell=True)
p.wait()

# open the results file and parse results
results = open('results.txt','r')
```

It works all right when I run it as stand-alone.

But my program needs to be a script that works from inside another application (PTV Visum: http://www.ptvag.com/software/transportation-planning-traffic-engineering/software-system-solutions/visum/).

When I run it as a script from there it seems I cannot get permissions to write files (results.txt). Thats the error message:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'results.txt'
```

How can I solve it.

PS. It tried os.chmod to change folder permissions but It didnt help

Comment: @agf You were right. Anyway that was strange, when I run it as a stand-alone `os.getcwd()` was proper throughout the process. But when I used it as a script `os.getcwd()` was something proper at the begining when I  monited it, and different after... Anyway I used: `os.chdir(good_cwd)` and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `print os.getcwd()`.

Your current working directory is not the directory where `results.txt` is being created.

The `IOError` is on the line where you read the file, not write it, because you're not specifying where to look for `results.txt`.